# Help me choose hardware configuration

Tags: stockfish, leela, hardware

I am preparing to buy a new desktop computer.

I would like to use it for chess analysis with both StockFish and Lc0.

My budget is slightly above 2K euros.

### QUESTIONS:

This is my first time choosing configuration for Lc0, so I do not know where to focus my attention.

Regarding StockFish, it should be simple? Just buff CPU + RAM and you are good to go?

Can you advise me, so I do not make a mistake during purchase (what are the things I should strive for, what to pay attention the most...)?

### MY EFFORT TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

After Googling a little, I believe that below configuration could suit me:

- CPU = AMD-AM4 Ryzen 9 3950X (16 cores, 3.5 GHz)
- MOBO = AMD-AM4 Asus TUF B450M-PLUS
- RAM = KINGSTON DDR4 32GB 2666MHz HX426C16FB3/32 HyperX Fury Black MEM01669
- GPU = Asus nVidia GeForce RTX 2070 ROG-STRIX-RTX2070-O8G-Gaming 8GB GDDR6
- Hard Drive = SSD 480GB Kingston A400 SA400S37/480G
- Computer Case = MS WINSTON gaming ATX
- Power Supply = LC Power 650W LC6650 V2.3 + Bronze
- OS = Windows 10 Home x64

Comment: I don't like to be one of those SE complainers who want to close every question ever, but are you sure this is the best place you can think of to get PC hardware recommendations? :-) I can look at Lc0's GPU benchmarks but I have no idea how to translate that to actual cards.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: After seeing [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-type-of-hardware-is-the-most-important-for-analysing-with-houdini) and the description of tag `hardware` it seemed pretty much on-topic... :(

Comment: you are completely right, I had no idea we had that tag :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest things that stand out here is the power supply and hard drive. For the first, getting a cheap power supply tends to be a bad idea since if it breaks, it can bring down a lot of other stuff with it. 650W is plenty, but I'd recommend going with a more established brand like corsair or silverstone. For the hard drive, given that you can get a 1TB SSD for about $150, I would do so since it will mean you have plenty of room for a 6 man tablebase (syzygy).

Other than that, this should be a really good system for both leela and SF. If you want any help with optimal settings for lc0 performance, feel free to drop by the lc0 discord!